# Mediaelement WPF with 2 video one is sometimes freezing

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I develop a desktop application using wpf and mediaelement.
There's 2 different mediaelement with all transport fonction play, pause, next/prev frame....
I have 2 problems in my application:
- Sometimes one video is freezing, it's often happen when I'm doing a play and then nextframe or nextframe many times on both video1 and video2.
- When I set the position of the video the image of the video does not always correspond to the position I setted.
Is there anyway to force the video to really refresh to the good position?
Any idea for the freezing staff?

Code for NextFrame:

```
m_currentMedia.Pause();
m_currentMedia1.Pause();

VideoStatus = VideoStatusEnum.Pause;
VideoStatus1 = VideoStatusEnum.Pause;

SpeedRatio = 0;
SpeedRatio1 = 0;

double NewPos = Math.Round(m_currentMedia.Position.TotalSeconds, 2) + 0.04;
TimeSpan NewPosition = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(NewPos);

double NewPos1 = Math.Round(m_currentMedia1.Position.TotalSeconds, 2) + 0.04;
TimeSpan NewPosition1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(NewPos1);

m_currentMedia.Position = NewPosition;
m_currentMedia1.Position = NewPosition1;
```

Comment: The MediaElement is fairly temperamental about seeking. Few questions: Is each MediaElement playing a different video file? What file(s) are being fed into the player(s), and what properties do they have? Are you able to inspect/provide the key frame interval for your video files?

Comment: The mediaelements are playing the same video file which is an mp4 file with a frame rate of 29 frame/s.

Comment: Does anyone heard aboud WPFMedia tool kit? Should it solve the instability problems of the mediaelememt?